# jQuery validate numeric textbox and given min & max value

Tags: jquery, validation

I wish to given my validation with min and max number and then giving a correct alert message. How to set min and max into the script below?

```
function isvalidated(){
    //CURN
    if(!$.isNumeric($('#txcurn').val())){
        alert("Please enter numbers");
        return false;   
    } 
}
```

Comment: have a look at http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @Alex can be more specific ?

Comment: you can use if...else conditions

Comment: @Kenny ya...i know but how to insert min and max ? can give me some example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using ternary operator :

```
function isvalidated(input,min,max){

    if(!$.isNumeric(input)){
        alert("Please enter numbers");
        return false;   
    } else {
        message = (input <= max) ? (input >= min ? "input is valid" : "input must be greater than "+min  ) : "input must be smaller than "+max; 
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

call it like :

```
isvalidated($('#txcurn').val(),1,10)
```

Comment: made an update to show how to call it with arguments

Comment: how to make it if #txtcurn equal to input then return true, if smaller or higher input than show alert